# Sending APDU command for reading a passive tag?

Tags: nfc, apdu, mifare, lib-nfc

I'm using libnfc and the apdu_examle.c with PN532 on my Beaglebone.
I have a android example for emulating Miffare classic 1k card HCE(Host Card emulation) on my phone and everyting is working fine. If I tap the phone I can read the message that I'm sending from my phone.

Is it possible to send apdu commands to read data from a Miffare classic 1k card (passive tag)? not phone. 
The card is ISO/IEC 14443A standard.
Must there be a specific format or data structure on the card?

Here are some more info about the card:

ISO/IEC 14443A (106 kbps) target:
    ATQA (SENS_RES): 00  04

- UID size: single
- bit frame anticollision supported
     UID (NFCID1): db  6c  10  2b
    SAK (SEL_RES): 08
- Not compliant with ISO/IEC 14443-4
- Not compliant with ISO/IEC 18092

Fingerprinting based on MIFARE type Identification Procedure:

- MIFARE Classic 1K
- MIFARE Plus (4 Byte UID or 4 Byte RID) 2K, Security level 1
- SmartMX with MIFARE 1K emulation

Answer (score 0):

MIFARE Classic does not operate with APDUs (ISO 7816 layer 4), but at layer 3 + proprietary extensions. As far as I know, it is not possible to communicate with it using HCE unless the phone has an NFC chipset from NXP.

But if your card is a SmartMX with emulated MIFARE, that means that you can send APDUs to the JavaCard OS. Have you tried sending a simple command, for example an empty SELECT `00A4040000`?

Comment: I tried to send 00A4040000 but I'm getting an error "Application level error". think I understand it I'm using "nfc_initiator_transceive_bytes" function from libnfc to send apdu commands but the tag does't understand this. So I need to send native commands, Is there a function in libnfc to send native commands in libnfc?  Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with libnfc so I can't really help you there, sorry. Maybe your card has that command somehow restricted.